# Can I add external jars into every project in IntelliJ and/or Eclipse?

Tags: intellij-idea, project, project-structure

i´ve been working with an external Intranet-Manager and i can load code-snippets into external editors like IntelliJ. My problem is, i want to use the libs of that manager-tool but the code-snippets are just temporary alive, there is no permanent project structure.
Is there a chance to get this done?

Comment: You explore in Google and you wil get first hit on how to add external jars. You have to add in your build path

Comment: Is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: Thats not the point. The point is, that there is no project structure to add external jars, every time i trigger "open intellij", the dependencies are gone, so i have to repeat the include. The open file is complete new, in a complete new folder.